# Use variable name in dot notation in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I use a variable name in the dot notation in Swift?

The code looks like this：

```
enum BitMaskCategory: Int {
    case coffeemug = 1
    case banana = 2
    case cup = 3
}

let selected = self.selectedItem
node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BitMaskCategory.selected.rawValue
```

The error message is：

> Type 'BitMaskCategory' has no member 'selected'

`selected` is a variable which contains the item I selected. `selected` can be one of "banana", "cup" or "coffeemug". For example, if I select "banana", `node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask` should equal to "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the selected item is a string I recommend to declare the `enum` `String` based and add a computed property to return the integer value

```
enum BitMaskCategory: String {

    case coffeemug, banana, cup

    var maskValue : Int {
        switch self {
        case .coffeemug: return 1
        case .banana: return 2
        case .cup: return 3
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write

```
let selected = self.selectedItem
node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BitMaskCategory(rawValue: selected)!.maskValue
```

Comment: `selected` doesn't contain the value of type `BitMaskCategory`. I have to use `selected` after `BitMaskCategory.` How can I use a variable name after the dot? Thanks.

Comment: So what type has the *selected item*? You cannot use an arbitrary variable name after a type.

Comment: It is a String.